# C# : Web page reloaded every time a button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a C# web application. In event handler of a link, I add a user control named addUser.ascx to application's Home page as follows:

```
addUser au = (addUser)LoadControl("UserControls/addUser.ascx");
content.Controls.Add(au);
```

The problem is that when I click on a button of user control, The entire page will be refreshed and the user control removed. How can I solve that? The button definition in user control is as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" Width="125px" Height="30px" BackColor="Green" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tahoma" TabIndex="7" />
```

**Edit:**
Home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Home" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"%>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="au" TagName="AddUser" Src="~/UserControls/addUser.ascx" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <telerik:RadSkinManager ID="QsfSkinManager" runat="server" ShowChooser="true" />
    <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="AddLink" OnClick="AddLink_Click" runat="server" Text="Add New User" />
        <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" PageSize="10">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id" Font-Names="Tahoma" Dir="RTL">
                <Columns>                    
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Password" HeaderText="Full Name" />                    
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="content" />
</asp:Content>
```

Home.aspx.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Home : Page
    {
        protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = new Domain().getAllUsers();
    }

    // some irrelevent methods here

    //
    protected void AddLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        content.Controls.Clear();
        addUser au = (addUser)LoadControl("UserControls/addUser.ascx");
        content.Controls.Add(au);
    }
}
```

}

addUser.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" CodeBehind="addUser.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.UserControls.addUser" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<div>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <div style="float: right;">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"/>
                </div>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <div style="float: right;">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click"/>
                </div>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
```

addUser.ascx.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1.UserControls
{
    public partial class addUser : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //add somthing to db
            // when this button clicked, the whole page will be 
            // refreshed and the addUser user control will be removed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start by reading how ASP.NET Web forms work and what is page lifecycle and postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use **ajax** and **asp:updatePanel** around the parts you want to be updated. A very nice example is described here : [A nice example on asp:updatePanel](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html)

Answer (score 0):

On button click event it is always send page to server side so it is refreshed each time when you click on button..

But you can use onclientclick instead of onclick..so it wont refresh your page ..

Comment: Thanks rushank. I did every thing you say but still same error exist. I remove onClick event from it but still page refreshing!!

Comment: can you post your whole code?? so i can answer of it properly.

Comment: my friend rushanak, the codes are added. Please help me